# How to get records from column by limiting

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make query which gets records where numbers match from 10 to 20 from column category and order by views(from column views).

I'm maked this :

```
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT category,views FROM mytable order by rand() LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20 ");
```

**UPDATE:**
THIS WORKING PERFECT!!!

```
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT category,views FROM mytable order by rand() BETWEEN 10 AND 20 ");
```

Comment: `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT \`category\`, \`views\` FROM \`mytable\` ORDER BY \`views\` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 9");`

Comment: I've got many times this error error:

C:\xampp\htdocs\functions.php on line 30
Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in

Comment: Do you have at least 20 rows in table?

Comment: yes, I've get success with BETWEEN

Comment: Edit your question by sharing successfull code you mentioned.